# selecting element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have an object in `HTML`:

```
<li id="m_delete" data-group="edit" class="m_delete edit-object disabled" data-control="delete" title="Delete"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="m_edit" data-group="edit" class="m_edit edit-object disabled" data-control="drag" title="Edit"><a href="#"></a></li>
```

Using next line I am selecting all element in specific class.

```
$("#toolbar .edit-object").addClass('disabled');
```

But how can I select just `delete` element from that class? What is wrong in the next line?

```
$("#toolbar .m_delete .edit-object").removeClass('disabled');
```

It is incorrect. How it can be fixed (select just delete object)?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#toolbar .m_delete.edit-object").removeClass('disabled');
```

you should remove the empty space between classnames to make your selector properly work (because you're looking for an element inside #toolbar with *both* classes)

but of course it's better to address the element with

```
$("#m_delete")
```

for the sake of performance (and because that id is unique in the page)

Comment: +1 for id selector - Haha just said that, but you updated. Nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select elements with both m_delete class and .edit-object class, you can use this selector:

```
$("#toolbar .m_delete.edit-object").removeClass('disabled');
```

I have removed the space, as it will select all .m_delete with child element .edit-object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your selector is that it selects all items which has a class `edit-object` and has a parent node with class `m_delete` which has a parent node with id `toolbar`.

You can translate it in your mind like this:

```
#toolbar // .m_delete // .edit-object
```

As [F. Calderan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11291438/221213) says in his post correctly you can match an item with both `edit-object` and `m_delete` class without a space in the selector: `.edit_object.m_delete`.

This can be translated to:

```
#toolbar // .m_delete & .edit_object
```